# Recognise Malformed XML file

Tags: python, xml, malformed

I am building a python script to run nightly, part of which involves invoking a drupal bulk operation to export an XML file. Since the process takes a number of hours, and the next step is to automatically import it to another source, I would like to perform some level of integrity checking.

My first thought would be to simply make sure that the XML is not malformed. I don't particularly want to start inspecting the data, I just want to make sure it's not truncated.

What process might I use to perform this malformed check. Is there an applicable XML library built into Python? I would prefer to keep the script as portable as possible, so if possible a built-in solution would be the most preferable.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Yes, there are XML libraries built in and also nice third-party ones as `lxml`, with which you can verify the XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want use python, you can consider using [element tree](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml)

Load your .xml and try to parse. Any Exception means XML is malformed.